# Converting measured S-parameter to Z-parameter does not match the Z-parameters measured on the same circuit

Tags: impedance, conversion, s-parameters

I have measured the S-parameters for a 4 port circuit. For a certain frequency those values are:

```
-4.500e-01-8.457e-01*i,    +2.138e-02-6.787e-03*i,    -5.095e-07-7.460e-07*i,    +1.957e-02-1.152e-02*i;
+2.137e-02-6.794e-03*i,    -4.117e-01-4.189e-01*i,    -7.185e-07-2.888e-06*i,    +5.716e-01-4.498e-01*i;
+1.148e-06-4.426e-07*i,    -7.622e-07-4.159e-07*i,    +1.000e+00+2.202e-03*i,    +2.588e-06-3.405e-07*i;
+1.961e-02-1.151e-02*i,    +5.718e-01-4.498e-01*i,    -3.237e-06+1.412e-07*i,    -4.120e-01-4.220e-01*i;
```

Implementing the formula from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_parameters in MATLAB, I came up with following lines of code:

```
SMeasure = [...
-4.500e-01-8.457e-01*1i,    +2.138e-02-6.787e-03*1i,    -5.095e-07-7.460e-07*1i,    +1.957e-02-1.152e-02*1i;
+2.137e-02-6.794e-03*1i,    -4.117e-01-4.189e-01*1i,    -7.185e-07-2.888e-06*1i,    +5.716e-01-4.498e-01*1i;
+1.148e-06-4.426e-07*1i,    -7.622e-07-4.159e-07*1i,    +1.000e+00+2.202e-03*1i,    +2.588e-06-3.405e-07*1i;
+1.961e-02-1.151e-02*1i,    +5.718e-01-4.498e-01*1i,    -3.237e-06+1.412e-07*1i,    -4.120e-01-4.220e-01*1i];
vSize=size(SMeasure, 1);
hSize=size(SMeasure, 2);
Z0=50;
E=eye(vSize, hSize);
Z0Mat=E*sqrt(Z0);
ZCalc=Z0Mat*(E+SMeasure)*(E-SMeasure)^(-1)*Z0Mat
```

The result from this code gives me following Z-parameters:

```
+1.434e+00 -3.002e+01*i,    -1.394e-01 -1.038e+00*i,    +9.933e-03 -2.221e-02*i,    -2.581e-01 -1.134e+00*i;
-1.398e-01 -1.038e+00*i,    +3.944e+00 -2.933e+01*i,    +2.067e-02 -5.808e-02*i,    +3.485e+00 -3.011e+01*i;
+2.530e-02 +2.201e-02*i,    +3.812e-02 -2.226e-02*i,    -3.357e+03 +4.518e+04*i,    +2.974e-02 +5.365e-02*i;
-2.571e-01 -1.135e+00*i,    +3.490e+00 -3.012e+01*i,    -4.340e-02 -1.214e-01*i,    +3.839e+00 -2.941e+01*i;
```

The above results are from matlab using the values with full precision as I got them from the 4-channel-VNA. Using the rounded values as shown in the code above I get with octave following output:

```
ZCalc =
   1.4336e+00 - 3.0026e+01i  -1.3938e-01 - 1.0379e+00i   8.3049e-03 - 2.2937e-02i  -2.5818e-01 - 1.1344e+00i
  -1.3988e-01 - 1.0383e+00i   3.9438e+00 - 2.9329e+01i   1.6403e-02 - 5.9578e-02i   3.4847e+00 - 3.0112e+01i
   2.6901e-02 + 2.0154e-02i   3.6486e-02 - 2.5048e-02i  -5.0000e+01 + 4.5413e+04i   3.3663e-02 + 5.1473e-02i
  -2.5716e-01 - 1.1353e+00i   3.4906e+00 - 3.0118e+01i  -5.2282e-02 - 1.1822e-01i   3.8385e+00 - 2.9408e+01i`
```

The Rohde&Schwarz network-analyzer also gives me the possibility to save my measurement directly as impedance values. Measuring again the same circuit and saving as impdeance values gives me the following values:

```
+1.460e+00 -3.001e+01*i,    +4.144e+03 +1.359e+03*i,    +5.979e+07 -6.182e+06*i,    +3.694e+03 +2.235e+03*i;
+4.144e+03 +1.350e+03*i,    +1.510e+01 -1.932e+01*i,    +1.809e+07 +2.869e+07*i,    +8.048e+00 +8.497e+01*i;
-3.922e+07 -2.166e+06*i,    -8.560e+06 +3.158e+07*i,    -1.276e+03 +4.563e+04*i,    +3.576e+07 +5.867e+07*i;
+3.689e+03 +2.236e+03*i,    +8.036e+00 +8.501e+01*i,    +6.542e+06 +2.735e+07*i,    +1.501e+01 -1.943e+01*i;
```

As they are from two separate measurements of the same circuit, I do not expect them to be exactly the same, but except for the diagonal values the values are completely different.

Comparing the measured S-parameters with the measured Z-parameters from Rohde&Schwarz, I have the impression that these are in a reasonable relationship. Comparing the measured S-parameters with the calculated Z-parameters, the calculated Z-parameters do not make sense.

I would be very glad if someone could tell me where I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Did you measure the s parameters with a 4-port VNA?

Comment: Yes. A Rohde&Schwarz 4 Port VNA.

Comment: My calculations do not meet yours ... What is "eye"? (diagonal 1 ?) Some formulas as your link (?). EE&O...

Comment: From the link I've posted I used the formulas in the section "Relation to S-parameters". I should had posted a more precise link like:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_parameters#Relation_to_S-parameters.

The "eye"-function in matlab creates a diagonal 1 matrix with the given size.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am wrong ... EE&O.
Here is what I get from my Maple sheet ... To be confirmed.

[image]

Comment: At my computer I'm on now only has octave. So I copied the lines above to verify the calculation. Octave gives me similar results. I assume, that the differences are due to roundings, as in matlab I had the numbers with full precision as I got from the VNA and in octave I only have the values acording to the precision of the printout.
The output from octave I will add to my question above.